# Semaphore dependency chain in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

Lets say I have two frames in flight and a single queue. Frame 1, which was submitted to the queue first and frame 2, which was submitted second. Now my understanding is that frame 2, i.e. the second queue submission may start before frame 1 is finished and it may theoretically even finish before frame 1, but semaphore for frame 2 wont be signaled until semaphore for frame 1 is signaled (because all previously submitted commands to the queue must complete). Thus there is sort of an "implicit dependency" of frame 2 on frame 1, i.e. by the time frame 2 is signaled, frame 1 is certainly finished too. Is that right ?